# std::vector segmentation fault during push_back

Tags: c++

I have a class named book, that contains books.

```
#ifndef BOOK_H
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#define BOOK_H
class book
{
public:
    std::string Author, Title;
    int Year;
    book(){}
    book(std::string author, std::string title, int year);
    ~book(){}
    void add_book();
    std::vector<book*>library;
};  
#endif
```

book.cpp file

```
#include "book.h"

book::book(std::string author, std::string title, int year)
:Author(author), Title(title), Year(year){} 

void book::add_book()
{
    int y;
    std::string a, t;
    std::cin>>a;
    std::cin>>t;
    std::cin>>y;
    library.push_back(new book(a, t, y));
}
```

But when I want to add a new `book` to the library, I'm getting a segmentation fault during the `push_back` of the new object in main.cpp file

```
#include "book.h"

int main()
{
    book* ptr;
    ptr->add_book();
    return 0;
}
```

Could someone explain to me what the problem is?

I'm new in OOP, and though I've read a lot of posts here I still can't find a solution.

Comment: The whole idea of having a separate library for each book looks a bit faulty to me. Also you declare `book*` but never initialize it and then call one of its methods.

Comment: FYI: class names are usually written in title case. This makes it easier for someone else to understand your code.

Comment: @OnMyLittleDuck: Class names are usually written in whatever style the class author follows, and I know plenty of programmers that follow styles that don't use title case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't initialise the `ptr` in `main`;

```
int main()
{
    book* ptr = new book(); // initialize it here
    ptr->add_book();
    return 0;
}
```

This will fix the segfault, however, I'm not sure of the logic associated with the sample code, and possible memory leaks.

---

I would look to separate the `library` from the `book` type for better composition and avoid the heap allocation;

```
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

class book
{
public:
    std::string Author, Title;
    int Year;
    book(){}
    book(std::string author, std::string title, int year) : Author(author), Title(title), Year(year) {} 
    ~book(){}
};  

struct library {
    std::vector<book> books_;
    void add_book(const book& value) { books_.push_back(value); }
};

int main()
{
    library lib;
    int y;
    std::string a, t;
    std::cin>>a;
    std::cin>>t;
    std::cin>>y;
    lib.add_book(book(a, t, y));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, here:

```
book* ptr;
ptr->add_book();
```

`ptr` is unassigned, so its use causes seg fault. You should assign it before use:

ptr = new book();

this will cause memory leak so I suggest (if you like dynamic allocation):

```
auto ptr = std::make_unique<book>();
ptr->add_book();
```

but, why you need pointer anyway, this:

```
book bk;
bk.add_book();
```

will work the same way.

---

On the other hand, why your `book`class keeps a vector of `book` instances? You need a `library` class which will keep a vector of book-s.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I will remember about that, unfortunately I'm working at c++11 compiler right now.
Can't answer this question now. I must practice more :) But thanks again for idea of creating second class.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make an object of class Book before using its methods.

```
Book *ptr = new Book();
```